# Using streams to find the highest unique values

Tags: java, java-stream

Let's say I have this simple Car object:

```
class Car {
  String id;
  String model;
  Integer price;  
}
```

Now I have a list of cars which might look like so:

```
{ Car(1, Commodore, 55000), Car(2, F150, 120000), Car(3, F150, 130000),
  Car(4, Camry, 50000), Car(5,Commodore,50000)}
```

I would like to filter any duplicate models out of the List, ensuring that I'm only keeping in the most expensive priced car of each duplicate, e.g:

```
{ Car(1, Commodore, 55000), Car(3, F150, 130000), Car(4, Camry, 50000) }
```

I believe that I can do this using the Streams API, but I'm just struggling to chain the right calls together.

In my head, I would imagine the pseudocode would be something like:

- Collect all the cars, group by model
- Use Collectors.maxBy() on each individual model's List to get the priciest
- Amalgamate the resulting one-item lists into a global car list again

Trying to stitch that together got a bit messy though - any ideas?

Comment: ``List<Car> res = cars.stream().collect(collectingAndThen(groupingBy(c -> c.model, maxBy(comparing(c -> c.price))),m -> m.values().stream().map(Optional::get).collect(toList())));``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `Map` of the max valued car by model:

```
List<Car> cars = new ArrayList<> ();
Map<String,Optional<Car>> maxCarByModel =
  cars.stream ()
      .collect (Collectors.groupingBy (c -> c.model,
                                       Collectors.maxBy (Comparator.comparing (c->c.price))));
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Collectors.toMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) with a merge function that keeps the car with the max price:

```
Collection<Car> carsWithMaxPrice = cars.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(
        Car::getModel,
        Function.identity(),
        (c1, c2) -> c1.getPrice() > c2.getPrice() ? c1 : c2))
    .values();
```